# How to parse aws-cli output using jq containing arguments using the --arg switch?

Tags: jq, aws-cli

I'm trying to parse the output of `AWS cli` using `jq` where the jq query contains bash variables and by using [the --arg switch](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) like so:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-instances --region $region | jq --arg environment "$Environment" --arg br "$BUILD_NUMBER" --arg app "$App" -r '.Reservations[].Instances[].Tags[]?.Value | select(startswith("Company-$environment-$br-$app")
```

I get a new line when I run the command.

This is the output when I use hard coded auto scaling group name:

```
itai@Itais-MBP ~/Downloads -  $ aws ec2 describe-instances --region $region |   jq --arg environment "$Environment" --arg br "$BUILD_NUMBER" --arg app "$App"   -r '.Reservations[].Instances[].Tags[]?.Value | select(startswith("Company-Dev-60-Api") )'
Company-Dev-60-ApiServersASG-19L10K16RUXTE
Company-Dev-60-ApiServersASG-19L10K16RUXTE
itai@Itais-MBP ~/Downloads -  $
```

You can see the values of the variables are set:

```
itai@Itais-MBP ~/Downloads -  $ echo $Environment
Dev
itai@Itais-MBP ~/Downloads -  $ echo $App
Api
itai@Itais-MBP ~/Downloads -  $ echo $BUILD_NUMBER
60
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jq language has its own way of combining variables. In jq, the expression you wrote:

```
"Company-$environment-$br-$app"
```

is just a vanilla JSON string.

One option would be to use jq's support for interpolation:

```
"Company-\($environment)-\($br)-\($app)"
```

Another option would be to use jq's string-concatenation operator, `+`.

You could also use `join("-")`.  And so on.